# using javascript to check internet connection

Tags: javascript, networking

What I am trying to do is check for internet connectivity, and if it cannot connect it tries again a few times. The code I am using currently to check is found https://gist.github.com/fryn/943537, as it seems to be the most promising (I had less luck with other solutions).

My problem is that the "serverReachable()" function seems to always return false, even when the internet is connected. Any suggestions? I am open to using other solutions, this is just the closest I have gotten so far.

Thanks!

Here is my code: (all the alerts are there for debugging purposes)

```
var attemptCount = 0;

    function onOffLine(){
      alert("start of onOffLine function");
      var z = "N";
      var connectionTest = serverReachable();
      if(serverReachable()){
        alert("found to have connection.");
        document.getElementById("connected").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("notConnected").style.visibility = "hidden";
        z = "yes";
        alertMe(z);
      }else if(connectionTest == false && attemptCount < 4){
        document.getElementById("notConnected").style.visibility = "visible";
        alert("No connection, recursing.." + attemptCount);
        attemptCount++;
        setTimeout("onOffLine()", 3000);
      }else if(attemptCount == 4){
        alert("all attempts failed.");
        document.getElementById("notConnected").style.visibility = "visible";
        z = "N";
        alertMe(z);
      }
    }

    function alertMe(z){
      if(z == "N"){
        alert("Browser is loaded;\nInternet not connected");
      }else if(z == "Y"){
        alert("Browser is open and ready");
      }
    }

    function serverReachable() {
      alert("serverReachable() called");
      var x = new XMLHttpRequest;
      x.open('HEAD', '/?' + +new Date, false);
      try {
        x.send();
        var s = x.status;
        return s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304;
      } catch (e) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on browser support needed, you could always use the [online/offline events fired by the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Online_and_offline_events)

Comment: You don't specify a server in the URL argument to `x.open()`. So it's using the same server that the script came from.

Comment: `serverReachable` works in my browser.

Comment: @esseks It may help to mention what browser you are using.

Comment: Latest stable Chrome. Anyway, the point was not "my browser supports it", rather "the code is working fine, problem is somewhere else".

Comment: I am using my college provided internet. School's firewall maybe?